# Making a (html) password field to allow access to something

Tags: html, passwords

I've got a wordpress site with ftp that has a bunch of public stuff that I don't care that people see, and then I want to add a 'private' area which only people with the password can access.  It doesn't have to REALLY secure, I won't be keeping my credit card info in there, but I'd like it to be semi-secure.

The way I'd like it to work:

Click wordpress link on homepage

V

Be prompted to insert a password (username not necessary)

V

redirected to a page with secure content on it.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Password-protecting_directories#Creating_a_.htpasswd_file_manually

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/password-protect-pages-3

> Password protection for both Pages and Posts is built into WordPress. Upper right hand corned on Edit Page or Edit Post - visibility >> pick Password Protect.

Comment: How can I make it so that the page requires the password every time I visit it?

Comment: Why make the user enter the password they already clearly know unnecessarily?